# Unresolved import

Tags: python, pip, package

I get this error for every single package that I have downloaded from pip whenever I type `import [package]` or any variation there off. This also means that the packages do not work. This is strange, since it used to work.

Edit: Apparently it works just fine on Jupyter Notebooks, but not in a normal python file.

Comment: have you installed multiple python installations?

Comment: No I only have Python 3.6.2 installed

Comment: instead of typing `pip install`, use `python -m pip install`.

Comment: All I get is "requirement is already satisfied".

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are installing the module in a wrong way, specifically, to improper directory (or python version).
you can alway check if module/package is installed or not by this:

```
pip list
```

if you can see the module in list, then it is installed, if not, then you need to install it properly.

sometimes you may have different versions of python installed, you install the package to version X and try to run it on version Z. all you need to do is to clarify your python version, check if the pip is referring to the python version by doing this:

```
pip -V
```

it shows the pip version along with the python version it is referring to.

**The BEST WAY**
always try to create a virtual environment and install packages there.
creating a virtual environment

```
python -m venv <VENV_NAME>
```

then activate it:

```
source <VENV_NAME>/bin/activate  # MacOS & Linux
<VENV_NAME>/Scripts/activate  # Windows
```

then, install your packages. there shouldn't be any problems after that.